# Creating a loop to create NDVI images from raster stacks and naming them from the file name

Tags: raster, r, ndvi, rstudio

I have been trying to write a loop to go through two folders of Sentinel 2 satellite images (Band 4 and 5) and get a NDVI for each date.

A stack is created for each band, some cropping and resampling to finally proceed to the NDVI calculation. I struggle with the integration of the NDVI calculation in the loop and the file name creation.

I'd simply want my loop to generate x files for x dates and then give these NDVI images the date as a name "YYYY/MM/DD.tif"
But I can't think of a way to do so, after a lot of unsuccessful trial and error.

```
path4 <- "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/Raster/BDA/quinq/quatre"
path5 <- "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/Raster/BDA/quinq/cinq"

#list files
files4 <- list.files(path4, pattern = "jp2$", full.names = TRUE)
files5 <- list.files(path5, pattern = "jp2$", full.names = TRUE)

ms5 <- stack()
ms4 <- stack()

for (f in files4){
  # loading a raster
  r4 <- raster(f)
  proj4string(r4)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r4)) 
  r4b <- crop(r4, emprise)
  
  ms4<- stack(ms4,r4b)
}


for (f in files5){
  # load the raster
  r5 <- raster(f)
  proj4string(r5)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r5)) 
  r5b <- crop(r5, emprise)
  
  ms5<- stack(ms5,r5b)
}

#Resampling : setting the Band 5 to the same resolution as Band 4 
b5_resamp <- resample(ms5, ms4)
```

Comment: I think the broken code here is distracting. Tell us what the files are called (so we can see where the date is encoded in the filename) and tell us if the matching band files have the same spatial extent (is this why you crop and resample?) and what `emprise` is? Is that your overall area of interest?